# finding if n out of m columns are null over each row using calculated column functions in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have the following table and I would like to get the number of nulls for each `SEQ_ID`

```
SEQ_ID   zScore for 7d  zScore for 14d  zScore for 21d  zScore for 28d  zScore for 35d
456        11.353           13.2922         9.0162           8.8533
789        8.5991                            8.8244                           5.7394
```

So for SEQ_ID `456` I would have 1 null
For SEQ_ID `789` I would have 2 nulls

Is there a way to do this without writing complicated case statements with brute force combinations in the Calculated column area using Spotfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a Spotfire custom expression not involving R.

This would give you the number of columns that are *not* null. If you know the total number of columns, you can easily turn it into the number of null columns

```
Len(RXReplace(Concatenate($map("[yourtable].$esc($csearch([yourtable],"*"))",",'-',")),'\\w+','Z','g')) -
Len(RXReplace(Concatenate($map("[yourtable].$esc($csearch([yourtable],"*"))",",'-',")),'\\w+','','g'))
```

[*yourtable*] would be the name of your data table. This acts on all columns.